# Parsing to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I was just working on a simple program that used RestSharp to send a POST method to a machine that enables an axis of motion.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://10.101.2.216/");
var request = new RestRequest("/api/task/library/command", Method.POST);
request.AddBody(new { command = "Enable X"});

...
```

I was wondering what actually happens on that last line.  What type of variable is created?  What is the compiler actually doing?  In other words, how does that get converted into JSON and why does it work?

Comment: RestSharp will serialize this anonymous class to string `{"command":"Enable X"}`

Comment: Are you sure this is using JSON? By default the request will use XML serialization. Here's the source for RestRequest : https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs

Comment: So the variable type is anonymous?  and then the compiler converts it to a string?

Comment: The machine I'm using only accepts JSON, and it process goes through.  Also I checked that it was being parsed correctly with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

Comment: It's synonymous with declaring a new class derived from `object` with a single public read-only property called `command`.  And then instantiating an instance of that with `"Enable X"` as the property value.

Comment: just looked into the compiler-generated code.  it shows the new property like you said.  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# 4.0 introduce anonymous types. Those types aren't defined by any specific type.
To construct anonymous type we use the `new { ... }` syntax. What RestSharp is actually doing it's using Reflection to serialize the type into JSON or XML.

Comment: I would give you an upvote, but I dont have the reputation yet, haha.  Thank you though